# Join table A into table B multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I have 2 tables in a mysql db (simplified example data):

```
Table 1: 3 names (unique)
Table 2: names (only from table 1), 3 dates, info
```

For each date there are sometimes all 3 names in table 2, sometimes less then 3.

Example for table 2:

```
d1 n1 info
d1 n2 info
d1 n3 info
d2 n1 info
d2 n3 info
d3 n3 info
```

Date 1 has got all 3 names, date 2 has got 2 names, date 3 hast got 1 name.

Goal: I need each "date" to have all 3 names. I can already filter 1 date from table 2 and join the tables successfully to have the desired outcome for one date, but how can I "add" all names to each date?

```
d1 n1 info
d1 n2 info
d1 n3 info
d2 n1 info
d2 n2 (added by the join, "info" is empty)
d2 n3 info
d3 n1 (added by the join, "info" is empty)
d3 n2 (added by the join, "info" is empty)
d3 n3 info
```

My real data has got much more names and dates, which makes individual joins impractical. It feels like there should be an easy solution to this, but I could not find any.

I also could do this with code ("for each date add missing names") , but I wonder if it can be done with sql

Working on MySQL 10.1.37

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want me to give an example of the mentioned join that I can already do?

Comment: No, and I don't want you to do anything you're not comfortable with. But, if you like , you may wish to read and act upon the information in the accepted answer at the link provided.

Comment: @david what is "added by join"? If no matching record exists for a name-date pair, what would the info column contain?

Comment: @SalmanA The info column would be empty on newly added names; I just need table 2 to contain each name for each date; newly added names do not have any information (yet)

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your input. I am not sure if you really think that CREATE and INSERT statements on my example data is necessary because of their simplistic structure. I just want to double check if I understand you correctly.

Comment: I promise you, I'm not in the habit of providing throw-away comments to questions (ok, maybe a little). Generally, if I suggest something, it's because it's really what I think. This is certainly no exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CROSS JOIN` to create all possible combinations of names and dates, followed by a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT name_table.name, datelist.date, info_table.info
FROM name_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM info_table) AS datelist
LEFT JOIN info_table ON name_table.name = info_table.name AND datelist.date = info_table.date
```

Comment: This sounds very much like what I am looking for, trying it out now.